# Math function always shows 0 or not work at all

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I made a simple math function to show users a calculation of one of my battle functions. 
But somehow I cant get it working.  I always get 0 no matter what I type in.

Javascript:

```js
function destroyMoon() {
  var deathstar = $('#deathstar').val();
  var moonBase = $('#moonBase').val();
  var moonSize = $('#moonSize').val();
  var result = Math.max(
                 Math.min(
                   Math.round(
                     (
                       100 - Math.sqrt(moon_size) * Math.sqrt((deathstar / (220 * Math.max(1, Math.pow(0.90, moonBase))))), 
                       1
                     ),
                     100), 
                   0
                 )
               );

  $('#moon_destr').text(NumberGetHumanReadable(result));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="list listOfOthers hard-table">
  <tr>
    <td>Check your moon destroy %
      <td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Moon base level<input type="text" size="10" value="0" name="moonBase" id="moonBase" onkeyup="destroyMoon();"></td>
    <td>Deathstars: <input type="text" size="10" value="0" name="deathstar" id="deathstar" onkeyup="destroyMoon();"></td>
    <td>Moon size <input type="text" size="10" value="0" name="moonSize" id="moonSize" onkeyup="destroyMoon();"></td>
    <td>Moon destroy chance
      <div class="text" id="moon_destr">&nbsp0</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You should split that whole expression you assign to `result` into smaller parts and then use the debugger to step trough the individual results. It looks like you have `Math.min(…, 0)` in your expression, but because it is hard to read, it is not possible to tell that for sure without splitting - or at least properly formatting- the expression.

Comment: This `Math.sqrt(moon_size)` might be a typo.

Comment: Still do not work if fix this.

Comment: @Maaverick I know that. I even tried to solve it but you need to simplify the formula. Its too complex and parenthesis might cause issues.

Comment: Okay, but I am just a beginner with Javascript and I made this function by checking out other function that I have and what work.

Comment: @Maaverick Its not about level. Also as T.niese suggested, you have `Mathy.min(..., 0)` and hence only 0 is coming. As to expression, assign individual value to variables and use them. Like `return 1 + 2 + 3` to `var a = 1; b =2; c = 3; return a + b + c;` This will help you resolve parenthesis issue

Comment: Okay thank you will try this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208961/discussion-between-rajesh-and-maaverick).

Comment: I updated the formatting for you, now you should see what the problem in your code is, and why it is important to split a complex express expression like this into smaller parts (or at least add some formatting as it did now)

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple problems in this expression:

```js
var result = Math.max(
                Math.min(
                  Math.round(
                    (
                      100 - Math.sqrt(moon_size) * Math.sqrt((deathstar / (220 * Math.max(1, Math.pow(0.90, moonBase))))),
                      1
                    ),
                    100), 
                  0
                )
              );
```

In your `Math.round` you have:

```js
(
   100 - Math.sqrt(moon_size) * Math.sqrt((deathstar / (220 * Math.max(1, Math.pow(0.90, moonBase))))), 
   1
)
```

Which is `( … /* that long expression * / … , 1)` do to the comma operator this evaluates always to `1`. So this is essential `Math.round(1, 100)`

So your code does this:

```js
var result = Math.max(
                Math.min(
                  Math.round(1, 100), 
                  0
                )
              );
```

The second argument of `round` is ignored so it is `Math.round(1)`.

And so the remaining code is: `Math.max( Math.min(1, 0) )`, which is always `0`.

You should move at least `100 - Math.sqrt(moon_size) * Math.sqrt((deathstar / (220 * Math.max(1, Math.pow(0.90, moonBase)))))` out of your expression and save it in a variable. And then us that variable in your `round`, `min`, `max` expression.

That way you can see if you have the correct braces and parameters.

So fixing those braces results into this:

```js
function destroyMoon() {
  var deathstar = $('#deathstar').val();
  var moonBase = $('#moonBase').val();
  var moonSize = $('#moonSize').val();
  var result = Math.max(
                 Math.min(
                   Math.round(
                     
                       100 - Math.sqrt(moonSize) * Math.sqrt((deathstar / (220 * Math.max(1, Math.pow(0.90, moonBase)))))
                     ),
                     100), 
                   0
                 )
               ;

  $('#moon_destr').text(result);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="list listOfOthers hard-table">
  <tr>
    <td>Check your moon destroy %
      <td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Moon base level<input type="text" size="10" value="0" name="moonBase" id="moonBase" onkeyup="destroyMoon();"></td>
    <td>Deathstars: <input type="text" size="10" value="0" name="deathstar" id="deathstar" onkeyup="destroyMoon();"></td>
    <td>Moon size <input type="text" size="10" value="0" name="moonSize" id="moonSize" onkeyup="destroyMoon();"></td>
    <td>Moon destroy chance
      <div class="text" id="moon_destr">&nbsp0</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It still not working not on JsFiddle not on my website, but thanks for trying out. I am still trying to correct the function

Comment: @Maaverick well I can't correct your code as it is not clear what parameters should belong to `min` and `max`. But it clearly produces results that are not `0` if those braces are corrected, as you can see in the snippet.

Comment: I understand that and thank you, I just use the formula what my PHP file is using to calculate the destroy chance and tryed to insert it in javascript, but seems like it will not work that way :D